# Scala Json(json4s) parse return None

Tags: json, scala, json4s

```
$             "properties": [
                {
                   "name": "Armour",
                   "values": [
                      [
                         "258",
                         1
                      ]
                   ],
                   "displayMode": 0
                },...]
```

I have this JSON array.

I use json4s and scala for parse this code.

```
case class Property(
    name: String,
    values: Option[Option[(String, Int)]] = None,
    displayMode: Int
)
```

I write case class for this block, but I get "None" when get values...

I need get "258" in this example.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Json looks like you have a list of lists under your values property. I guess you want to have something like dictionary which should be with curly brackets instead of just brackets. Other thing is why would you parse that into Option[Option[(String, Int)]]? Try defining that as optional Map[String, Int].

Comment: Yes, but I get a JSON just brackets instead of curly brackets. And I just do not understand how to handle it. It is not a list of lists.
I use Option because without it breaks down the entire Property, and with it - only values

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
values: List[(String, Int)] = Nil
```